# Sending Mp3 File via tcpserver to a client

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

i have a tcp client as below:

```
 public static void RunStream()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting Stream...");
        TcpListener listen = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 13000);
        listen.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");
            Socket socket = listen.AcceptSocket();

            if (socket.Connected)
            {
                SendFile(socket);
                socket.Disconnect(false);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void SendFile(Socket socket)
    {
        NetworkStream netstream = new NetworkStream(socket);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(netstream);
        FileStream fileStream = File.Open("file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        fileStream.CopyTo(netstream);
        netstream.Flush();
        netstream.Close();

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunStream();
    }
```

and a client that reads and save the stream (which contains the mp3 file) from the server like this:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 13000);
        
        byte[] bytes = new byte[2100000];
        var stream = client.GetStream();
        int i;
        while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
        {
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, i);
        }
        File.WriteAllBytes("test.mp3", bytes);
        stream.Flush();
        client.Close();           
    }
```

the issue is that i got only a snippet of the original mp3, for example if the origianl file has a 24 seconds duration i only get the first 5-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bro in client you wrote `stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)` this mean you rewrite array every time reading data
and you using a big array for save your data and if you send a big file this will make problem
its better code like this bro :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 13000);

        var stream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024]; //you can change length later, bigger arrays have more reading speed but give more ram
        FileStream filestream = new FileStream("test.mp3", FileMode.Create);
        while (stream.Length > stream.Position)
        {
            int readLength = stream.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
            filestream.Write(buff, 0, readLength);
        }
        stream.Flush();
        client.Close();
    }
```

Comment: now i get this error "This stream does not support seek operations.'
"

Comment: in the while condition

Comment: @Leo but for me is fine. what is your .Net framework version?

Comment: .Net core 3.1 on both, server and client

Comment: @Leo i imported code in a .Net core 3.1 project but cant find any error ,is (Error) originally meant (Runtime Exception)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233352/discussion-between-leo-and-amirhosein-adlfar).

Comment: @Leo i cant join to chat that page returned 404 error ... are you have telegram?